# objshell.run with variable

Tags: variables, vbscript, wsh

I have resolved all but one line in my script.
the \server\printer is hardcoded (for testing) and I would like to turn it into a variable.

```
StrPrintername = "\\\realserver\realprinter"
```

```vb
objShell.run "cscript ""%SystemRoot%\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\prnmngr.vbps"" -ac -p ""\\SERVER\PRINTER"" ",1,true
```

Comment: Where does `AddQuotes()` function come from you've not included the definition? To be honest just double the quotes is the way to do this like you have done already against the script path. `cscript ""%SystemRoot%\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\prnmngr.vbps"" -ac -p """ & StrTempPrinter & """,1,true` will produce `cscript "%SystemRoot%\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\prnmngr.vbps" -ac -p "\\realserver\realprinter",1,true` when it runs.

Comment: AddQuotes() was something i found online.

Comment: I tried adding, exta " and it didn't work. (Unterminated String)

Comment: This works for me just tested it `objShell.run "cscript ""%SystemRoot%\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\prnmngr.vbps"" -ac -p """ & StrTempPrinter & """",1,true` you sure the error isn't something related to the `prnmngr.vbps` you are running?

Comment: Just saying it didn't work isn't very helpful when someone is trying to help you. Please detail the exact error you get when what you try doesn't work, I'm guessing it's no longer `Error 0x800A0409, Unterminated string constant`.

Comment: this time you have four quotes at the end.  This time no errors but the command is too quick to read.  it doesn't add the printer.  The vbs script i am using is part of windows so you should be able to also use. (if you wanted to try :) )

Comment: GRATE! it works, sorry, somehow a mistake got in there.